# How can I connect my Samsung S3 Mini to Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, samsung, mtp

I have tried many things including the installation of gMTP from Ubuntu's PPA, and with it many other that include mtp-dev... I have forgotten now the bunch of files I have installed.

The problem is that when I plug my S3mini into my computer it is not recognized, however if I change the way of connecting form MTP to PPT (I believe is PPT the other way) it does connect, and if I go back to MTP again it does connect. The problem is that I cannot move big files from and into my cellphone's internal storage.

I know and I use *Airdroid* for small files, I have Dropbox but my internet is limited and slow, and both options (Airdroid and Dropbox) take years in copying a movie onto the cellphone.

Comment: What version of Android? (on phone)

Comment: Confirm which version of Ubuntu, eg. **12.10**

Comment: Android 4.1.2 and Ubuntu 12.10 (with gnome shell and no unity, I don't know if it is relevant)

Comment: I have both Android and Ubuntu up-to-date with the different updates.

Comment: I check # mtp-connect and I got this 'diego@diego-Ubuntu:~$ sudo mtp-connect
[sudo] password for diego: 
libmtp version: 1.1.4

Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung GT P7310/P7510/N7000/I9070/I9100/I9300 Galaxy Tab 7.7/10.1/S2/S3/Nexus/Note/Y.
PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
LIBMTP PANIC: failed to open session on second attempt
No devices.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution by updating some packages from a PPA...

I've found the solution in this page:

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/upgrade-to-gvfs-with-mtp-support-in.html

Answer (score 0):

*I have an S3 Mini (Android **4.1.2**), and am able to connect to **12.04 LTS** using various methods ..*

I have used MTP mode, and modified **udev** rules. Then I need to run a mount / unmount commands. *Really quite cumbersome, but still workable.*

I found just using **SSHDroid** (free Android app.) over WiFi was simpler, faster, and reliable. I can SSH (command line) and connect (to server) from within Nautilus.

I have Ubuntu **12.04 LTS** on my main PC, but can probably re-test these methods on **12.10**. There is a major update for MTP (for **12.10**) that will probably provide a simpler solution (long term).

Comment: And with SSHDroid how is the data transfer speed? Similar to Airdroid or faster?